# android facebook login with android facebook sdk with setting login accout

Tags: android, facebook, sdk

Please clear my doubt. I have Facebook sdk 3.0 above. I have task that, i have android app which have button when i click it has to take user account from my settings->account>Facebook. Then it let me to post some message.

(That mean has to allow to default login of my device Facebook. then let me to post).